# .NET Core - AWS KMS - EncryptionMaterials issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I have been trying to use the KMS manager to encrypt and store some sensitive information in an S3 Bucket. I found plenty of examples on how to do this, the most  significant being the one in AWS Documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/kms-keys-s3-encryption.html)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Encryption;
using Amazon.KeyManagementService;
using Amazon.KeyManagementService.Model;

namespace S3Sample1
{
    class S3Sample
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string kmsKeyID = null;
            using (var kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient())
            {
                var response = kmsClient.CreateKey(new CreateKeyRequest());
                kmsKeyID = response.KeyMetadata.KeyId;

                var keyMetadata = response.KeyMetadata; // An object that contains information about the CMK created by this operation.
                var bucketName = "<s3bucket>";
                var objectKey = "key";

                var kmsEncryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(kmsKeyID);
                // CryptoStorageMode.ObjectMetadata is required for KMS EncryptionMaterials
                var config = new AmazonS3CryptoConfiguration()
                {
                    StorageMode = CryptoStorageMode.ObjectMetadata
                };

                using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(config, kmsEncryptionMaterials))
                {
                    // encrypt and put object
                    var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName,
                        Key = objectKey,
                        ContentBody = "object content"
                    };
                    s3Client.PutObject(putRequest);

                    // get object and decrypt
                    var getRequest = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName,
                        Key = objectKey
                    };

                    using (var getResponse = s3Client.GetObject(getRequest))
                    using (var stream = getResponse.ResponseStream)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

}
```

This code as is does not work, even if I use the Full framework (to use the example above in .NET Core I had to make all aws calls async as per their documentation) version because

```
var kmsEncryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(kmsKeyID);
```

Does not accept a string but either a AsymmetricKey or SymmetricKey Object. I went around it by

```
var kmsEncryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(RSA.Create())
```

Obviously this would be a per session key, so I actually found this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/client-side-data-encryption-with-aws-sdk-for-net-and-amazon-s3/, that basically details how to reuse a key this seems really outdated (created on 2013) and in my opinion defeats the point, of my usage as I initially wanted to use KMS as the actual authentication/authorization provider for all of our boxes in the aws ecosystem to then access the S3 bucket containing the secret key.

Am I missing something? Why does the AWS example has a string in it?

I am using the latest packages for AWS SDK .NET Core:

- AWSSDK.Core - v: 3.3.24.4
- AWSSDK.KeyManagementService - v: 3.3.6
- AWSSDK.S3 - v: 3.3.20

Answer (score 0):

After almost a day or so with this problem I realised the issue was to do with multiple targets of the Amazon.S3.Encryption dll.

I found a github project that had the example correctly working against .net core (https://github.com/priyalwalpita/awssdk_dotnetcore) and from them it was very clear that the problem was with my cached dlls.

I've also triple checked by ItemGroups in the csproj and made sure they were correct

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.3.24.4" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.KeyManagementService" Version="3.3.6" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.20" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Hopefully this might help somebody in the future